# Merge two existing forms together, Add PHPBB2.x posts in to an existing SMF1.1x

Tags: php, database, forum

I have two community website each running their own forms and I would like to merge the content of both forum in to one forum. Specifically from (PHPBB 2.x) in to a SMF (1.1). Both forums have been running for years now and have built up 100k of posts each.

I found a converter that converts PHPbb 2.x to SMF here 
http://download.simplemachines.org/?converters;software=phpbb
But when I install and run this script I get the following warring

*All or some of the data in your installation of SMF will be overwritten.*

So what I am really looking for is a forum merge not a convert.

Suggestions on how to do merge two forums databases together in to a single database.?

Comment: I assume that i will have to convert the PHPbb form in to a fresh install of SMF then somehow merge the two SMF together... But I'm not sure how I would go merging the two SMF together.

Comment: I found this post http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=20341.0 apparently its a huge pain to do this. Has anyone had any experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very difficult task due to the certainty of conflicting IDs and users. Like your link suggests, you'll first have to check for any duplicate users. Aside from that, every post and user should have a unique ID, and those IDs will be referenced in many places (e.g. the userid would be referenced in the posts table).

One solution I have used in a similar situation is to add a number to all the IDs in one database. If you have, say, 3k users, add 5,000 to all user IDs, across all the tables they are referenced in that database. Do the same with individual posts (probably need to add 100,000 or more). And the same for anything else with unique IDs.

After that, you can copy the data to the other database. Obviously, do this on a test server first (e.g. `localhost`).

Of course, the other answer is to scrap all the old posts and start again - is a discussion from 2005 all that useful?